# How to load Tile faster without any blink while moving map using flutter_map?

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, fluttermap

### Description:

Mapbox is integrated in flutter using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) package and few more layer are added on it flutter_map children like marker, cluster, etc...

### Issue:

While we move the map or do zoom in/out in map than tiles are loading after a second so it look like a blink before new tile is loaded. Please check current output and required output below.

#### Current code:

```dart
TileLayer(
  urlTemplate:
      "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/user/clgp8xzs200b301qm7i8k8xo4/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token={accessToken}",
  additionalOptions: const {
    'accessToken': AppConstants.mapBoxAccessToken,
  },
  tileProvider: NetworkTileProvider(),
),
```

##### Tried solutions:

- flutter_map_tile_caching: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map_tile_caching
- `keepBuffer` property in `TileLayer`

##### Solutions needed:

- Load tile smoother and faster without any blink while we move or pinch the map.
- Even if required a second to load tile then blink should not be visible.

#### Current output:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jLeD_2F1WhoLkevCKMUkYFZ32kueWINL/view?usp=sharing

#### Required output:

- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X-ulYpTPD1vVeeUQqd9ucTdoPPxSmxbS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Google maps are working fine don't know anything about flutter map.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think it is because flutter_map only supports raster tile.There are plugins to support vector tiles in flutter_map.Not sure though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).